# VXML visualizer (free/open-source)

Tags: voice, vxml, xml-visualizer

I am trying to visualize a VXML file, and have been searching for hours for a free and if possible open-source application, that would run on Windows, despite my intensive search I could not find any application.

Does anyone know a VXML visualizer?

Comment: In my case, I use eclipse with vxml's XML Schema. It isn't best solution, but very easy.

Comment: the issue is that i want a visualization, otherwise a usual xml tool will due it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Eclipse Voice Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/vtp/). This open source tool lets you visually develop a voice application that runs on any VoiceXML 2.1 compatible system.  The only problem with this tool, and any other VoiceXML tool, is they store the information as meta-data that is translated to VoiceXML either at deployment or at run-time.  This will lock you into a tool vendor since it will not be portable from one tool to another.  There are not any tools, open source or commercial, that can take straight VoiceXML and visually represent a higher level abstraction of the voice application.

Comment: I already tested it, I couldn't handle it, in my case, I think it doesn't work or our VXML-files are too odd.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there are not any tools that reverse engineer existing VXML. Each tool stores the visual representation of the voice application in their own proprietary format. They do not work with VXML directly.  What are you hoping to achieve by visually representing your existing VXML?

Comment: my hope was to view the basic flow chart of a set of vxml files, so that i can easily move on to parts of the xml file, that are relevant and do not have to check each line of code in the files

Comment: I am still not very statisfied, because those tools can not handle all types of VXML files, but I accept this answer (formally) as correct.